# Sticky Notes project in WPF. Model, View, ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am working on a Sticky Notes project and doing the UI in WPF and obviously resorting to MVVM as my design choice for architecture. I am having second thoughts on what should be my Model, View and ViewModel.

I have one class that is called Note, here is how it looks like:

```
class Note
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

And I also have User, which stores collection of Notes:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Guid, Note> Notes = new Dictionary<Guid,Note>();
}
```

So now I need to make my Model and ViewModel. First I was thinking to go with the most obvious approach, which is the Note itself is the Model, then have a NoteViewModel for the ViewModel. But then I thought, what if I make User as the model and have a UserViewModel class for the ViewModel. And if I do so, how do I implement INotifyPropertyChanged. If my model was Note, INotifyPropertyChanged implementation is straightforward. Your thoughts on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what?? the UserVM should have a list of NoteVM. simple as that. I dont understand your question. Also, don't use dictionaries in place of lists. Dictionaries overcomplicate the thing and add unneded extra code.

Comment: Dictionaries and Lists usually have no place in view models. Perhaps you meant ObservableCollection.

Comment: I am not putting Dictionaries or Lists within the view model

Comment: UserVM having a list of NoteVMs sound like an interesting idea. So, what you're saying HighScore is to have a seperate ViewModel for Note then another ViewModel for User. Then should I just bind the events in the NoteViewModel to the events in the UserViewModel? Will that be acceptable ? I can do this in so many ways, I just want to do it the right way. It's not just getting the work done, it's following the best pattern practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more illustrative way on how to do this is available on YouTube. Bottom line is that the UserViewModel will be the parent view model, and the multiple NoteViewModels will be child view models. The parent view model will be responsible for creating the child view models. Enjoy the video and like the author says - happy coding!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dzv8CtUCchY

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to broaden you idea of a model.  To put it simply:
The model is the representation of the "objects" you will be working with (which can be a database with tables or POCO's like you have defined).  The User and Note are both potentially part of the model in the same way that a **client** table and **clientOrders** table are part of the model in a database.  The ViewModel handles the business logic that interacts with the model and exposes that data to the view through wpf property binding.

As for INotifyPropertCHanged, here is a simple use (vb):

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Property CustomerName() As String 
        Get 
            Return Me.customerNameValue
        End Get 

        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If Not (value = customerNameValue) Then 
                Me.customerNameValue = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged()
            End If 
        End Set 
    End Property
```

c#:

```
 using System.ComponentModel

 public string CustomerName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customerNameValue;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.customerNameValue)
                {
                    this.customerNameValue = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

hope this helps